# R NameValue from CSV String - access value via name

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and have a question not knowing how to solve it. Maybe you can help?

I do have a separated `name`/`value` input string: `param1=test;param2=3;param3=140;`
I would like to access a value via it's name in R.
Something like using 
`myParams["param1]`

I already tried something like:

```
 input = "param1=test;param2=3;param3=140;"
 output1 = strsplit(input,";")[[1]]
 output2 = do.call(rbind, strsplit(output1, "="))
```

to get a matrix but am missing the rest..

Comment: Is your data in a file? If so you could use techniques from here http://rprogramming.net/read-csv-in-r/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a custom function `myParams`:

```
# Your sample data
input = "param1=test;param2=3;param3=140;"
output1 = strsplit(input,";")[[1]]
output2 = do.call(rbind, strsplit(output1, "="))

# Define function
myParams <- function(par, df = output2) {
    return(df[which(df[, 1] == par), 2])
}

myParams("param1");
#[1] "test"
myParams("param2");
#[1] "3"
```

Comment: No worries, glad to help @TomEgg.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to create a dataframe out of that matrix first and then access the value via row names

```
input = "param1=test;param2=3;param3=140;"
output1 = strsplit(input,";")[[1]]
output2 = do.call(rbind, strsplit(output1, "="))

temp =  data.frame(output2,row.names = TRUE)

#         X2
#param1 test
#param2    3
#param3  140

temp[,"param1"]
#test
temp[,"param2"]
#3
temp[,"param3"]
#140
```